# How do I deal with a void pointer to an array for sorting algorithm?

Tags: c, sorting, pointers, quicksort, void

I'm trying to make a generic quick sort algorithm in C that takes a void array as input. My question is how do I deal with indexing into that array. Below is my current attempt to do so with my partitioning function. My code compiles, but I know it's not accessing the correct pointers and this leads to segmentation faults.

```
static int partition(void *array, int left, int right, size_t elem_sz,
                  int (*comp) (const void*, const void*)) {
    // TODO
    void** arr = array;
    void* p = *(arr + left);
    int s = left;
    for (size_t i = left+1; i<=right; i++) {
      if ( (*comp)(*(arr + i), p) < 0 ) {
        s++;
        swap(*(arr + s), *(arr + i), elem_sz);
      }
    }
    swap(*(arr + left), *(arr + s), elem_sz);   
    return s;
}
```

Comment: You need to convert it to `char *` so you can do pointer arithmetic on it.

Comment: Why `char *` instead of any other type? And does this mean instead of `void** arr = array` I should be doing something like `char* arr = array`?

Comment: `char` is the smallest type. If you used some other type, you'd need fractions for the offsets.

Answer (score 2):

Converting your array pointer from `void *` to `void **` doesn't make sense, as you (most likely) don't have an array of `void *`.

To do the proper pointer arithmetic, you need to first convert the pointer to a `char *` since you can't do pointer arithmetic on a `void *`.  Then, because the size of a `char` is 1, you need to multiply the index by the element size to get the correct offset.

```
static int lomuto(void *array, int left, int right, size_t elem_sz,
                  int (*comp) (const void*, const void*)) {
    char *arr = array;
    char *p = arr + left*elem_sz ;
    int s = left;
    for (size_t i = left+1; i<=right; i++) {
      if ( comp(arr + i*elem_sz, p) < 0 ) {
        s++;
        swap(arr + s*elem_sz, arr + i*elem_sz, elem_sz);
      }
    }
    swap(arr + left*elem_sz, arr + s*elem_sz, elem_sz);   
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the void pointer to a char pointer so you can perform arithmetic on it. `char *` is used because `char` is the smallest type, and `elem_sz` will be multiples of `sizeof(char)`.

You don't need to dereference the pointers when calling `comp` and `swap`, just pass the calculated pointers.

All the indexes and increments need to be multiplied by `elem_sz`.

```
static int lomuto(void *array, int left, int right, size_t elem_sz,
                  int (*comp) (const void*, const void*)) {
    char *arr = array;
    void *p = arr + left*elem_sz;
    int s = left*elem_size;
    for (size_t i = left+elem_size; i<=right*elem_size; i += elem_size) {
        if (comp(arr + i, p) < 0) {
            s++;
            swap(arr + s, arr + i, elem_sz);
        }
    }
    swap(arr + left, arr + s, elem_sz);   
    return s;
}
```

I haven't examined the sorting algorithm itself to tell if it's correct, this just shows how to deal with the pointers correctly.